# Content is off screen on iPhone 6s simulator - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have developed a simple application which display listview on Xamarin Form. When I run my code on iphone 5 simulator, it shows what I expect, however when I run on iphone 6s, it does not show the data on the screen, screen is off from the screen.

```cs
var listView = new ListView
{
    RowHeight = 40
};
listView.ItemsSource = new string []
{
    "Categories",
    "Customer Demographics",
    "Customers",
    "Employees",
    "Order Details",
    "Orders"
};
Content = new StackLayout
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Children = { listView }
};
```

[image: iphone 5 screen capture]
[image: iphone 6s screen capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me on the **iOS Simulator** for the **iPhone 6 Plus OS 8**.

If you are testing on the simulator then you may have to scroll the **ListView** up to see the top of the screen as things don't exactly fit well on the Mac simulator window with not everything being displayed unless your lucky to have a large monitor.

Also, you should be offsetting from the top-of the screen using something like the following to take account for the **iOS** bar at the top of the screen to offset slightly so things are better displayed:-

```
objStackLayout.Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.OnPlatform(20,0,0), 0, 0);
```

Comment: What is your device configuration, I am using macbook 13". Even though I am scrolling up to see the content, once I scroll and leave it then it re-scrolls back to initial position.

Comment: Macbook Pro 15".  I had to resize the simulator window so that it fitted on the screen however.  Afterwards you can then scroll the contents of the simulator window by the two-finger gesture, same as normal.  I didn't experience any auto-scrolling back to the initial position however.